# Framework 7 XMLHttpRequest cannot load in PhoneGap desktop app

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap-desktop-app, html-framework-7

I'm new to Framework7, and currently using Framework7 and PhoneGap to build mobile app.

I installed PhoneGap desktop app and iOS PhoneGap app.

I'm following the get started code from Framework7 website.

When I use my iPhone to connect PhoneGap desktop app server, the ajax does not load. But I use android to connect the PhoneGap desktop app server, the ajax is working.

I feel that is the error below caused the ajax didn't load. This error message shows when its open the html file in my local C.

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Is it normal when using iOS to load ajax in PhoneGap desktop App? Is it will be working after I use PhoneGap generate the iOS .ipa file?

I afraid that, after I implemented my app and its does not work in iOS..

Answer (score 1):

@jasper
*Phonegap Build* is a cloud-based build service. If you are using *Phonegap Desktop App* then you should be using *Phonegap Developer App*. *Phonegap Desktop App* will not work with *Phonegap Build* - as is.

*Phonegap Desktop App* is a testing and learning App. It is not intened as a final product (or a real product). If you followed the directions on the "Get Started" on the homepage, and get to [Step 5: Going Further](http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/5-going-further/) it says:

> There are two choices available for building and packaging your applications:
>
> - Build and package locally using the PhoneGap CLI
> - Use PhoneGap Build cloud service for simplifying the build and app packaging process

This means you MUST use one or the other. AND you can *no longer* use *Phonegap Desktop App*.

Here a canned message I regularly post:

#### Canned Message

I need to blog this, so i don't have to repeat this answer again and again.

You cannot use *Phonegap Desktop App* with *Phonegap Build*.

*Phonegap Desktop App* uses *Phonegap CLI*, so if you want to use *Phonegap Desktop App* you need to stay with *Phonegap CLI*.

If you want to use *Phonegap Build*, then forget what you have done and start over  ***OR***  make [Minor modifications](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/tutorial-html5ui-hide-show/wiki) to move *Phonegap Desktop App* to *Phonegap Build*. To be clear, the difference is minor, but enough to keep tripping you.

Also, you will not be able to use *Phonegap Developer App* as that is meant to work with *Phonegap Desktop App*. You cannot use either CLI or Build with *Developer App*.

FWIW: I've been trying to get Phonegap to fix this. Here is the [report on the issue.](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-docs/issues/137)